# How to add a loading mask layer in my bootstrap single-page webapp

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, underscore.js, mask

I am using:

- Bootstrap
- jQuery
- Backbonejs
- Underscorejs

to develop a Single-Page Application.

When I load a view, I want add a loadig mask before the view is really loaded. **How to do that? It's better to use bootstrap or jquery internally.**

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Display your loading image in the render function, and start to sync your Model. when your model get synced, replace the loading image with real view. the real view may created by JQuery.

And this:

Make a view just for display loading image, let its $el hold the element where your want display your real view, and show it. Then initialize your real view, its's $el hold the same element as loading image view did. after the initialization finished, just call render() on it, and it will replace the loading image automatically.

But:

Backbone are too simple to called as framework. [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) is recommended, it based on Backbone, and provide some hook to interacts with view's life cycle.